# javascript slideshow grow faster, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slideshow

I have an ad slide-show on my homepage. It consists of 2 images.

I preload these 2 images, making `new Image()` and setting `.src` to them.

I have a function `giveNextName` that return name of the next image (that should be in `src` attribute of the `img` element) (I do this, because soon, slideshow will consist of more than 2 images)

So the main code looks like:

```
BillBoard               = {};
BillBoard.folder        = "/pictures/cards/";
BillBoard.ext           = "png";
BillBoard.$             = $("#billboard img");
BillBoard.pics          = 2;
BillBoard.changeTime    = 7000;
BillBoard.names         = ["ad1","ad2"];
BillBoard.currentState  = 0;       
BillBoard.images        = // array of preloaded Images

(function(){
    var image, images = [];
    for (var i=0; i<BillBoard.pics; i++) {
        image = new Image ();
        image.src = BillBoard.folder+BillBoard.names[i]+'.'+BillBoard.ext;
        images.push (image);
    }
    return images;
}());

BillBoard.giveNextName = function(){/* getting the next name */};

// BillBoard change action
BillBoard.change = function(){
    BillBoard.$.fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', BillBoard.giveNextName());
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
}

// Starting BillBoard
window.setInterval(BillBoard.change, BillBoard.changeTime);
```

So, idea is simple. with `window.setInterval` I call `BillBoard.change` every n seconds. But, I don't know why, billboard becomes changing faster and faster, until there will be no picture at all (fadeIn doesn't have time to execute)

Where is my mistake?

**UPD**. Thanks to **Yann Ramin** for the link.

I shouldn't call `BillBoard.change` every n seconds via `window.setInterval`. Instead, I should add call of `BillBoard.change` in the callback of `fadeOut()`.

I mean this code:

```
BillBoard.change = function(){
    BillBoard.$.fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', BillBoard.giveNextName());
        $(this).fadeIn();
        window.setTimeout(BillBoard.change, BillBoard.changeTime);
    });
}

// simply call the change function
// it will be calling itself every n seconds
BillBoard.start = (function(){
    window.setTimeout(BillBoard.change, BillBoard.changeTime);
}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this for a likely culprit:

http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2011/07/jquery-fadein-window-setinterval-a-bad-combination/